# Problems with dataframe object in conversion to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I´m new to programming in Python and I´m trying to code a program that reads a xlxs file and converts it to json. (I´ve been using Python 3 and 0.23.0 version of pandas for it, but I've had some problems and difficulties with it.)

===========================

**There are two rows with four columns each in my xlsx file:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil

92    Hong Hong      CUST-88888         China
```

===========================

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Plan1')

list1 = []
list  = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list.append ({
            "id"       : int(row['id']),
            "label"    : str(row['label']),
            "Customer" : list1
            })

    list1.append ({
           "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
           "label"    : str(row['label_customer'])
           })

print (list)

with open ('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list, f, indent= True)
```

========================

**Json Output:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

========================

**What is expected:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

========================

I've already tried to append list1 before add it in the list, but doesn't solved the problem.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What about using df.to_json?

Comment: He wanted to get both id_customer and label_customer into one subdictionary , otherwise .to_json would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not empty list1 at the end of the loop. This causes list1 to grow in size at the end of every loop. Simply empty list1 at the beginning of each loop to get your desired output. See code below (I changed variable `list` to `list_final` because list is a type and you shouldn't have variables with the same names as types):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    list1  = []
    list_final.append ({
            "id"       : int(row['id']),
            "label"    : str(row['label']),
            "Customer" : list1
            })

    list1.append ({
           "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
           "label"    : str(row['label_customer'])
           })
```

The output is now what you expected:

```
print(list_final)
[
{'id': 6, 'label': 'Sao Paulo', 'Customer': [{'id': 'CUST-99992', 'label': 'Brazil'}]}, 
{'id': 92, 'label': 'Hong Kong', 'Customer': [{'id': 'CUST-88888', 'label': 'China'}]}
]
```

Comment: Okay!! The code is working now, thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code was nearly working - first off you should prob. avoid using builtin names like 'list' for you varaibles - and second you had the order a bit backwards. I changed a few lines and wound up with:

```
file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx')
print(file_imported)
list1 = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list1.append({
            "id"       : int(row['id']),
            "label"    : str(row['label']),
            "Customer" : [{'id':str(row['id_customer']),'label':str(row['label_customer'])}]
            })

print(list1)

with open('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list1, f, indent=True)
```

which seems to do what you were after.
Incidentally you can also do this with a df.apply if you wanted.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.. the problem is that "Customer" is like a key of my list1 and should begin with '[' (not '{').

Comment: I added a list around the dictionary in my last edit